# Postfix as email forwarder to gmail, SPF problems

Tags: postfix, spf, forwarding

I'm trying to configure [postfix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postfix_(software)) as forwarder to [Gmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail). I've successfully configured the [virtual aliases](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_alias) for the domains I'm hosting and that I want to redirect, but the Gmail [Sender Policy Framework (SPF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) verification is failing due to this:

```
Delivered-To: realrcpt@gmail.com
Received: by 10.25.28.147 with SMTP id c141csp88155lfc;
    Sat, 11 Oct 2014 09:08:40 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.224.70.83 with SMTP id c19mr21300511qaj.66.1413043720159;
    Sat, 11 Oct 2014 09:08:40 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <realsender@gmail.com>
Received: from mail1.mycompany.com (mail1.mycompany.com. [2604:xxxxxxx:b5c8])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id d63si16549011qgd.80.2014.10.11.09.08.39
    for <realrcpt@gmail.com>;
    Sat, 11 Oct 2014 09:08:40 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning realsender@gmail.com does not designate 2604:xxxxxxx:b5c8 as permitted sender) client-ip=2604:180:2:2cf::b5c
```

I think the problem lies in the return path. When doing email forwarding with another hoster (e.g. [namecheap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namecheap)) that gets rewritten to this automatically:

```
Return-Path: <SRS0+BJjl=7C=gmail.com=realsender@eforward3e.registrar-servers.com>
```

Is there any way to perform such a rewrite in postfix?
Thanks

Comment: You need an SPF record that includes your server. This can be configured in the DNS Settings of your Namecheap account. If you provide a domain name, I will provide an answer with SPF record recommendation.

Comment: Problem is that it's checking the SPF record on gmail, not on my domain...

Comment: Gmail will check SPF records of all incoming mail. If you are sending mail as username@gmail.com, then there is no way to pass the SPF check, as you are not the owner of gmail.com.

Comment: It checks on the Return Path, which postfix has to rewrite. See my answer, I managed to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this with postsrsd by following this guide: [https://www.mind-it.info/forward-postfix-spf-srs/](https://web.archive.org/web/20211012213920/https://www.mind-it.info/forward-postfix-spf-srs/)

In short:

### Download and compile the software

```
cd ~
wget https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd/archive/master.zip
unzip master
cd postsrsd-master/
make
sudo make install
```

### Add postfix configuration parameters for postsrsd

```
sudo postconf -e "sender_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:10001"
sudo postconf -e "sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender"
sudo postconf -e "recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:10002"
sudo postconf -e "recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient"
```

### Add SRS daemon to startup

```
sudo chkconfig postsrsd on
# Start SRS daemon
sudo service postsrsd restart
#Reload postfix
sudo service postfix reload
```

https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd was still maintained in 2023 which mentions in the [`README.rst`](https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd/blob/main/README.rst)

> If your Linux distribution has a sufficiently recent PostSRSd package, install it! Unless you need a specific new feature or bugfix from a newer version, it will be much less of a maintenance burden.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for me, maybe I am missing something.