# Postfix change "From: " address when redirecting received email

Tags: postfix

When redirected, received email from my server preserves the original `"From: "` address, which isn't favorable since that address may (and usually do) have SPF protected domain, among other reasons.

This looks like:

- a mail is sent from `forexampleaddr@gmail.com` to email address `name@domain.tld` hosted at my server,
- a mail is delivered to `name@domain.tld`
- a mail is forwarded to `othername@otherdomain.tld`. `otherdomain.tld` rejects the email since my server isn't eligible to send `@gmail.com` emails.

How can I deal with this: can I **rewrite** "From: " address but only in case when email is redirected and according to some map?

---

It is a standard Virtualmin email setup with Postfix and `/etc/aliases`.

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
```

/etc/postfix/virtual

```
name@domain.tld    name.domain
```

/etc/aliases

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
clamav: root


name.domain: othername@otherdomain.tld,\name.domain
```

Answer (score 3):

Preserving the `From:` is not a problem since SPF checks are not done against the `From:` header. In fact, it is a great idea not to touch the `From:` header since emails from `@gmail.com` usually have this `From:` header signed with DKIM.

You need to rewrite the [envelope sender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_address), which you may see in the email headers as `Return-Path:`. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/635300/114782) provides one possible solution to your problem. To quote it here:

> I fixed this with postsrsd by following this guide:
> https://www.mind-it.info/forward-postfix-spf-srs/
>
> In short:
>
> ### Download and compile the software
>
> ```
> cd ~
> wget https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd/archive/master.zip
> unzip master
> cd postsrsd-master/
> make
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> ### Add postfix configuration parameters for postsrsd
>
> ```
> sudo postconf -e "sender_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:10001"
> sudo postconf -e "sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender"
> sudo postconf -e "recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:10002"
> sudo postconf -e "recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient"
> ```
>
> ### Add SRS daemon to startup
>
> ```
> sudo chkconfig postsrsd on
> # Start SRS daemon
> sudo service postsrsd restart
> #Reload postfix
> sudo service postfix reload
> ```

Comment: Thanks for answer, ↑ vote so far. Definitely not happy because of need for 3rd party daemon to perform what I thought it's natural for Postfix to have a built-in way.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to rewrite from address from an external mailservice, as I would then redirect it to gmail. I had found that canonical has helped me do that.

```
/etc/postfix/sender_canonical has a list of mappings of external addresses to internal addresses. This will make the relayed email appear to be sent from my domain and match the pointer record lookup of my mailserver-IP

http://postfix.cs.utah.edu/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#canonical
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).