# Issue with postfix configuration as relay server

Tags: postfix

I have created a postfix server for my domain : residencebauge.fr.

I have also configured SPF to authorize only my public IP address : "v=spf1 a:vps.residencebauge.fr ip4:51.77.220.62 -all"

I have then configured DKIM and DMARC and when I check in different website, everything seems correct.

When I send an email directly from the server everything seems OK and the mail is never considered as SPAM :

```
echo "TEST" | mail -a "From: admin@residencebauge.fr" -s "TEST" oterrien@gmail.com
```

But, my postfix server aims at relaying emails to several addresses in @residencebauge.fr. Like mailing lists in fact.

To do that, I defined my mailing list in virtual map. For example:

```
test@residencebauge.fr oterrien@gmail.com
```

When someone sends an email to test@residencebauge.fr, I would like this email is sent to oterrien@gmail.com without being considered as a spam.

But it is not the case and emails are considered as spam.

When I send email from oterrien@neuf.fr to test@residencebauge.fr, the mail is received in oterrien@gmail.com as a spam.

In headers I can see:

```
Received: from vps.residencebauge.fr (vps-3a4b84af.vps.ovh.net. [51.77.220.62])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id j2-20020adfe502000000b002dd02867a56si8919660wrm.263.2023.04.17.14.11.17
        for <oterrien@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Mon, 17 Apr 2023 14:11:17 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 51.77.220.62 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of oterrien@neuf.fr) client-ip=51.77.220.62;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@neuf.fr header.s=202006 header.b=ZYIsEzPx;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 51.77.220.62 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of oterrien@neuf.fr) smtp.mailfrom=oterrien@neuf.fr
Authentication-Results: vps.residencebauge.fr; dkim=pass (2048-bit key; unprotected) header.d=neuf.fr header.i=@neuf.fr header.a=rsa-sha256 header.s=202006 header.b=ZYIsEzPx; dkim-atps=neutral
```

I guess the issue is because "google.com: 51.77.220.62 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of oterrien@neuf.fr" but I don't find what to do to fix it.

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Please provide your postfix configuration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postfix as email forwarder to gmail, SPF problems](https://serverfault.com/questions/635293/postfix-as-email-forwarder-to-gmail-spf-problems)